# Overflow on channel while Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

i'm facing this error while using flutter_web, anyone can tell me the solution about it.

Overflow on channel: plugins.flutter.io/path_provider.  Messages on this channel are being discarded in FIFO fashion.  The engine may not be running or you need to adjust the buffer size if of the channel.

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation
>   found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel
>   plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)

Comment: `path_provider` isn't supported in Flutter web. See: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45296